# Ambiguous handler methods when trying to create generic rest api controllers

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have quite a few repositories in my app and we need REST endpoints for them. Due to certain requirements, the default implementation of spring-data-rest is not effective and thus I wanted to write my own implementation. Initially I started by writing a controller for each of my entity like thus:

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("/myEntity")
@ExposesResourceFor(MyEntity.class)
public class MyEntityResource {
    @GetMapping(value = "", produces = MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity getResult(@RequestParam final MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters) throws IllegalAccessException {
        // my logic
    }
}
```

Writing this boiler code for all the rest endpoints associated with the repositories seems like a lot of work and thus I was thinking of writing a generic controller for all repositories taking ideas from `RepositoryEntityController`. So I created a controller like

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class ApiResource {

    @GetMapping(value = "/{repository}", produces = MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity getResult(@QuerydslPredicate RootResourceInformation resourceInformation, @PathVariable String repository) throws IllegalAccessException {
            // my logic
    }
}
```

This is pretty much how `RepositoryEntityController#getCollectionResource` is defined but this throws a `Ambiguous handler methods mapped for '/api/v1/myEntity'` exception indicating my method and the `RepositoryEntityController#getCollectionResource` method.

How do I cleanly override the default implementation?

Comment: *Due to certain requirements, the default implementation of spring-data-rest is not effective*. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Ask a question about your problem with SDR repositories and not your perceived solution.

Comment: @AlanHay My reputation here might not precede me in here but I am sure that I am not in an xy situation. I know exactly what to achieve and want to know if that certain use case is implementable or not.

Comment: What is it you want to do that requires custom controllers?

Comment: I am using spring acl which does not work with pagination and as such I had to work through custom logic while retrieving from the repositories in my service classes. As such, I plan to call the correct service class based on the entity whose endpoint is called and get the resultant dataset.

Comment: lol. maybe you are still in an xy situation. I'm working on a Spring Data Rest Acl extension. (although I called it beta, I already use in a production code) https://github.com/BerryCloud/spring-data-jpa-acl/tree/master/acl. I believe it solves all of your ACL and paginated list problems. If not, then you can find a solution in the source for overriding the default SDR controller.

Comment: See the com.berrycloud.acl.configuration.rest.AclRepositoryRestConfiguration#restHandlerMapping class/method in the source.

Comment: @Selindek I have come across your library before and have considered using it but later decided to implement it myself. I would like to try it once I have got some bandwidth but I had a question. In your library, when you make a paginated call, does the database query for that call fetch all the records or do you make sure to only fetch the records from the db that is required in the response.

Comment: I add a special `Specification` to all queries (created on the fly) so the filtering happens in the DB. Only the records which required are returned from the DB.